# Arbitrage argument and Market Quotes

Tags: finance, arbitrage, finance-mathematics, econometrics, financial-markets

Good day, I wanted to ask for help with a question from one of my exercise sheets.

> For a share S the market quotes a given strike K in both european and
>   american styles. Use an arbitrage argument to construct a formula
>   relating the price of the european call option to the price of an american call option.

I do not understand what is meant by EU and US style Market quotes. From my research, it just seems that

- EU is quoted at K USD per share
- US is quoted at $\frac{1}{K}$ shares per 1 USD

But this does not tell me much about applying an arbitrage argument. I have no idea about the formula that relates the two styles.

Comment: I think they mean European = exerciseable at maturity only.  American = exerciseable at any time up till maturity.

Comment: @dm63 Having said that, what would the formula then be? If we assume some sort of interest rate and apply it to the strike K, would that help in answering the question?

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some words. Perhaps you meant "construct a formula relating the price of the european **call option** to the price of an american **call option**" ?

Comment: Hint:  If European options can only be exercised at maturity, and American options can be exercised any time including at maturity, which options would have more value?

Comment: I would assume the US ones would have more value.

Comment: Actually, European and US style call options always have the same value, as (in the absence of dividends) it is never worth to exercise the European option early. For puts, the US option _can_ be more valuable, if the risk-free rate until the expiry exceeds its time value.

The top answer to this question might be of help. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5161/why-are-american-style-options-worth-more-than-european-style-options

Comment: @ʎpoqou:  The next point to consider--when would it matter if one had the additional opportunity to exercise?

Comment: I think the immediately apparent conclusion you can derive is the inequality that American option >= European option.  Proof:  you can always achieve equality by exercising the American option at maturity only.